# Interpolation in angular-translate for html injection

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to work out how to translate large blocks of html with angular-translate (which I'm using as a filter).

I've got language json files:

```
{
  "PURPOSE": "Sie Damit Beabsichtigt",
  "INTRO_VID": "Sehen Sie sich das Intro-Video",
  "TOUR": "An der Tour teilnehmen",
  "PURPOSE_COPY": "<p>Die Idee hinter [snip]</p><p>Currency: {{vm.testAmount}}</p><p>Date: {{vm.testDate}}</p>"
}
```

then in the html I take a language string and pass it to the translate filter with the data from the view model (`translate:vm`) and finally to the htmlSafe filter, which allows it to be parsed into html:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="'PURPOSE_COPY' | translate:vm | htmlSafe"></div>
```

The htmlSafe filter looks like:

```
angular.module('kitchenapp').filter("htmlSafe", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    };
}]);
```

The html is injected into the page fine, but does not compile, even though I passed the view model to translate. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, whatever you pass to `translate:<expression>` is taken as the scope. If you want to pass your actual scope then pass `translate:this`. Above I passed vm and then looked for vm.x: That equates to vm.vm.x, which obviously doesn't exist.